# Can Maven3 play nicely with non-Maven projects in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, maven, classpath

I have a project that depends on a library that is only easily available through Maven (OpenIMAJ). I have set up a Maven 3 project in NetBeans 7, and can develop my code that way. I would like to integrate the build product from this Maven project into a larger NetBeans project that does not use Maven 3. What's the smoothest way to get the JAR output from the Maven build process into my Netbeans (non-Maven) project, with the proper dependencies in the classpath?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Build & install Maven-project to local Maven repository (Or deploy to shared repository)
2. In non-Maven-project, express a dependency on the JAR (?) built by Maven-project just like you would for any other JAR

Comment: Really? I don't believe that will grab the dependencies for that jar.  Do the dependencies of the maven project (mentioned in step 1) get included in the jar expressed as "a dependency" in step 2?  I don't think so.

Comment: @Jason: You raise a good point.  I got lulled by the "the JAR output" statement (I assumed a singular JAR).  That said one could coerce transitive JARs into the Maven build artifact if the Maven packaging were "ejb".